# Internal testing with my children - Google Family Link blocking?

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I am developing an android game, which I would now like to test with my children (it's an online game, so playing it with my family seems like an obvious option at this point). So I've uploaded it on Google Play Console, and set up an internal test. My wife was able to install it using the link I sent her, but when my children (9 years old) tried, they got an error message stating the the app was blocked by parental control and could therefore not be downloaded.

The only parental control software I use, is Google Family Link. I've temporarily tried to allow all apps (regardless of age limit), but that didn't work. Is internal testing simply not available for children, or is there some setting I've overlooked?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue right now, did you find a workaround ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I've had to resort to installing the app using a USB cable connecting my child's phone to my computer.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way unfortunately =(

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is very simple. Simply complete the survey for the ESRB rating. as long as your app isn't rated higher than what your family link allows, for example, rated Mature when your kid's restrictions are set to E10, then they should be able to download it n no problem. the reason it blocks them from downloading it in the first place is because family link always blocks you from downloading unrated apps. hope this helps someone